# OpenSessionInView Pattern

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a web application that uses Spring 3.0.1, Struts 2.0, Hibernate 3.3.2 and Apache Tiles and I want to introduce the OpenSessionInView Pattern. I already added the filter in my web.xml file, but I don't know what to do next.

Web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<display-name>
    Struts2Hibernate3Spring3Tile2Integration
</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>articles.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>
        org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG
    </param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles-def.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Filtre pour OpenSessionInView -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

ApplicationContext.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- On demande à Spring de gérer l’ensemble des classes package ma.ecommerce -->
<context:component-scan base-package="ma.ecommerce" />
<!-- Pour accéder aux paramètres définis dans le fichier database.properties -->
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

<!-- La définition du bean sessionFactory en utilisant Spring ORM et Hibernate -->
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>ma.ecommerce.service.modele.Article</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"></property>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"></property>
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}"></property>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"></property>
</bean>


<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="article" class="ma.ecommerce.presentation.action.ArticleAction" />
<bean id="articleBean" class="ma.ecommerce.domaine.ArticleBean" />
<bean id="articleDao" class="ma.ecommerce.dao.DaoImpl"/>
```

DaoImpl.java file

```
@Repository("articleDao")
public class DaoImpl implements IDao 
{
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Override
public void saveArticle(Article article) 
{
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(article);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Article> getArticleList() 
{
    return       (List<Article>)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Article.class).list();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only thing missing is committing and closing the session after your view is rendered. Maybe you can do it with a Filter:

https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/OpenSessionInView

But you should think twice if you really want to work with the "Open Session in View" (anti-) pattern. At first it sounds like an easy solution to avoid LazyLoadingExceptions, but you should be aware of the penalty it's bringing along:

- working outside of an atomic transaction scope, so no isolation level configuration can be applied
- every additional request during the rendering process will be executed in auto-commit mode so the database has to do more work
- the session are possibly kept open longer than needed

Maybe you can figure out which fields are really needed and prepare a projection / DTO inside your service layer which is propagated to the view instead. This would discharge the database and encapsulate changes of data.

The question is here, do you really need access to the database inside your view?

Comment: thank you !, yes i have a part in my application where a client can add, edit, delete or list his articles and i need to access the database, and by the way this is kind of a homework and i was asked to use OpenSessionInView...